# Uniform convergence of series

Tags: uniform-convergence

We consider the sequence $(f_k)$ defined by $f_k:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, $f_k(x)=\dfrac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^k}$ for each $k\in \mathbb{N}$.

I already proved that $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}f_k$ converges pointwise in $\mathbb{R}$.

My question is, does $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}f_k$ converge uniformly?

Thanks.

Comment: You can compute the limit function, $f$, explicitly: $f(0)=0$. For $x\ne0$, using the formula for the sum of a Geometric series, we have $f(x)=1$. Note $f$ is not continuous ...

Comment: Oh, you're right. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

A full answer to this question (it was already partially answered in the comments):

Define 
$$
g_n(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}f_k(x)\\
=\frac{x^2}{x^2+1} \sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{(1+x^2)^k}\\
=\frac{x^2}{x^2+1}\frac{1-[1/(1+x^2)]^{n+1}}{1-[1/(1+x^2)]}\\
=\frac{x^2}{x^2+1}\frac{1-[1/(1+x^2)]^{n+1}}{[x^2/(1+x^2)]}\\
=(1-[1/(1+x^2)]^{n+1})
$$

The pointwise limit of this function is 
$$
g(x)=\begin{cases}1 & x≠0 \\ 0 & x=0 \\ \end{cases}
$$
Since this continuous sequence approaches a non-continuous pointwise limit, we may conclude that the sequence does not converge uniformly.

(Thanks for the correction David)

Comment: The value in line three of the sum in line two is off. It should be $x^2{   \color{maroon}{ [1/(1+x^2)^1]} - [1/(1+x^2)^{n+1}\over {1-[1/(1+x^2)] } }$.

Comment: Good catch; I was wondering why our answers were different.