# Analysis of $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^k}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Given the sum $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^k}$, I have two questions. (Sorry for that, it's for my exam preparations):

1. Prove that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^k}$ converges uniformly on $[a,\infty)$ for $a>0$
2. Prove that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^k}$ does not converge uniformly on $[-a,a]$ for $a>0$.

(I showed that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^k}=1$)

Comment: Note that at $x=0$, the sum comes out to $0$ rather than $1$, as is true for all other $x$.  In other words, the partial sums (which are each continuous) have a non-continuous pointwise limit.  What does that tell you about uniform convergence?

Comment: @GitGud Why not? see related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/414136/uniform-convergence-of-series/414262#414262

Comment: @Omnomnomnom You're right. My intuition betrayed me. Comment removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

$$1.-\;\;\;\;\forall\;x\,,\;\;0<a\le x\implies\frac1{(1+x^2)^k}\le\frac1{(1+a^2)^k}\;\;\text{and Apply Weierstrass $M$-test}$$

$$2.-\;\;\;\;\text{Use what you say you proved and check what happens for}\;\;0\in[-a,a]\ldots\ldots$$